# Does light itself experience time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, time-dilation

This seems weird for me. Every time I see light, I will think, "Hey, that light travels from the past far away from us!"

Correct me if there is misconception.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you think light experiencing time dilation entails.

Comment: Based on the special relativity, time is not constant. The faster we go the more time slows down. The photon travels at the speed of c. So, is the time of the photon slowed down or stopped?

Comment: I don't think light can "experience" time at all.

Comment: If you could attach a clock to a photon ,''somehow'',then the clock will show no reading,thats what mean by ''time stops at the speed of light''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In special relativity, time dilation is determined by the Lorentz factor 
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
Say the photon travels some time $T$ in our frame of reference. It is obviously travelling at the speed of light. We see that the Lorentz factor diverges as we go to the speed of light. Thus, in order for the photon's time in our frame to remain finite, its proper time must tend to zero. This is the colloquial "time stops at the speed of light."

Answer (score 0):

The way to measure time dilation would be to compare the time the moving object measures (its proper time) to the proper time of an observer. The problem with light is that proper time is defined as:

$$d\tau=\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu} $$

In flat spacetime $g=\eta=\text{diag}[-1,1,1,1]$. Now, with light, the line element $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=0$ so proper time makes no sense. In a way photons are frozen in their own time, but there is not much sense in saying that because talking about time doesn't make sense at the speed of light.

The comparison I mentioned earlier could be made, in SR, comparing the moving object with proper time $\tau$ to a resting object whose proper time is the coordinate time $t$, this gives:

$${{d\tau} \over {dt}}=\sqrt{-\eta_{\mu\nu}{dx^\mu\over dt}{ dx^\nu \over dt}}=\sqrt{1-v^2}$$

The last equality suming indices and with $c=1$. This shows that proper time is null for the speed of light. No much sense then in talking about time for the movement of massless particles.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the light travels from a place in the far past. However, the light itself does not experience the passing of time.

In relativity, there is an important distinction to be made between massive objects and massless objects.

For massive objects you can always find a frame of reference where they are at rest. In this frame time passes at "a normal pace".

However, for massless objects, no such frame exists. That is in a nutshell why light always travels with the same speed. As a consequence of there being no rest frame for light, it does not feel the passing of time.