# What is the velocity of a photon through the three spatial dimensions? What is its velocity relative to $x^4$?

Tags: spacetime, velocity

Two questions here:

What is the velocity of a photon through the three spatial dimensions?

What is its velocity relative to x4?

Comment: The velocity is $c$ of course. As $x^4$ are you confusing the exponent with the coordinates $x^4=ct$?

Comment: three spatial dimensions are x1, x2, x3.  fourth dimension is x4.

Comment: Please would you add some context to your question to explain its significance?

Comment: Yes Sammy! What is the velocity of a photon through the three spatial dimensions?  

What is its velocity relative to x4?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the velocity of a photon through the three spatial dimensions?

Velocity is **defined**  for a particle, with (x,y,z,t) coordinates as (dx/dt,dy/dt,dz/dt) , a three vector in space. Speed is the squre root of the dot product of velocity, and for a photon it is c, independent of coordinate frames because of special relativity.

> What is its velocity relative to x4?

x4 is time, and in [special relativity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) , ([a pseudo-euclidian  vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space)) no velocity can be defined in a logical manner, since time is involved in the definition of velocity and dt/dt has no meaning. In general, in contours  , for example 3d maps, dx/dy has a meaning, but not dx/dx.

Edit: To continue on the contour trail , there exist [dt/dx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation)  variations, i.e changes in time as a function of a space coordinate, that is what time dilation is in special relativity. Due to the mathematics of special relativity zero mass particles moving at velocity c have [undefined  dt/dx,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/does-light-itself-experience-time-dilation) is another way of looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

The photon does not have a well defined four velocity, $U^{\mu}$, because it does not have a well defined rest frame.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58098/discussion-on-answer-by-cstaralgebra-what-is-the-velocity-of-a-photon-through-th). I also removed some comments which were not constructive.

Comment: Yes!  That is how you interpret the math.  But this is a physics site.  What is the photon physically doing? What is the velocity of a photon through the three spatial dimensions? What is its velocity relative to x4?